# {"error":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"Failed to decode token."} "aibo developer"

Tags: curl

So Im trying to retrieve my Aibo device id.
Using windows 10 CMD shell with this admin privs…

```
curl -X GET https://public.api.aibo.com/v1/devices -H "Authorization:Bearer ${ I paste in my token string }"
```

I'm getting the error in the subject.

Both Aibos and my laptop are on the same network.

Comment: did you remove `${` and `}` when you tried?

Comment: that did the trick! my first time using curl and that wasn't obvious.. thanks!